# How can I iprint to string?

Tags: rascal

With `iprint` I can print an AST or with `iprintToFile` I can print it to file.

I can print to file and then read the file.

How can I iprint to string?

Answer (score 1):

That function seems to be missing from the IO standard library module.

A (dirty) work-around:

```
str iprintToStr(value x) {
  filename = |tmp:///iprintToString|;
  iprintToFile(filename, x);
  return readFile(filename);
}
```

You could also use one of the in-memory filesystems, like: `|test-temp://iprintToString|` which is faster than the `tmp` scheme.

It would be great if you register an issue with the usethesource/rascal project on github. Thanks

Comment: I submitted an issue

Comment: There exists a function itoString that can do this.